# Retrieving data with .Value and .ChildAdded

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a list of data to retrieve from Firebase, using Swift.
I tried to get the data using `.Value` and Firebase returns a dictionary with the IDs of each item and for each ID the info associated.

The endpoint I am calling is */ideas*.

```
    let ideasRef = firebase.childByAppendingPath(IdeaStructure.PATH_IDEAS)
    ideasRef.observeEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.value)
        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })
```

In order to optimize this, I changed with `.ChildAdded`. In this case I get only the single item without the ID associated.

Is it possible to get also the ID of each item using `.ChildAdded`?

If not, how can I save the ID generated by Firebase into each item? Currently I am saving each item in this way:

```
    let ideasRef = firebase.childByAppendingPath(IdeaStructure.PATH_IDEAS).childByAutoId()
    let idea = [
        IdeaStructure.FIELD_MESSAGE: message,
        IdeaStructure.FIELD_CREATOR_ID: userId,
        IdeaStructure.FIELD_CREATION_DATE: NSDate().formattedISO8601
    ]
    ideasRef.setValue(idea)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the key of the snapshot, access its `key` property:

```
let ideasRef = firebase.childByAppendingPath(IdeaStructure.PATH_IDEAS)
ideasRef.observeEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.key)
    print(snapshot.value)
}, withCancelBlock: { error in
    print(error.description)
})
```

This and many more topics are covered in [Firebase's excellent programming guide for iOS](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html).